# Simple Database design good enough for a lot of users

Tags: database-design

I am in the design stages for building a Car Racing game. Each user can have up to a 100 cars, where each car has its data stored within a record found in my Car Table. The fields within the table include:

```
<car_id, user_id, top_speed, colour, handling, acceleration ...>
```

-Where the user_id is a foreign key mapping to the car's owner.

My question: Is it ok for this simple design to store all of my users' cars within a single table? Lets say the app is successful and has around 10,000 users each having 100 cars. That would be 1,000,000 records in my car table. Is it an issue with regards to performance ? Can I help performance through the database's design?

Lastly, I plan to use MySQL as my DBMS.

Comment: Yes. It is okay. Just make sure you have good indexes

Comment: I would add indexes to it.

Comment: Assuming you have cars with id's `0` to `100`. Will car id#5 have the same specs for each player? Because in that case you could have a single cars table for all users and just link to the car table from the user's table.

Comment: @JakeParis what do u mean? each record found in the Car table has a primary key, denoted by car_id.

Comment: @JakeParis nope, I plan to make them customisable through tune ups etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it in the same table.

Unless you have a [specific reason for a surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info), make the relationship identifying...

[image]

...and [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the `car` table on the resulting natural key `{user_id, car_no}`. This way, cars belonging to the same user will be stored **physically close** together in the database, and the query such as: "give me cars of the given user" can be answered extremely fast.

---

On top of that, consider whether you actually need the 1:N relationship (as opposed to M:N). Will users ever share cars (or at least some "common aspects" of cars)?

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to user_id if you plan on having a lot of car lookups by user. Other than that there's no clearer way to optimize this design.

Comment: You could actually have a mapping table if you have cars with identical specs.

Comment: He said the user would "own" the car. I would only use a mapping/join table if the user didn't edit the car specs.

Comment: If a user edits the car they would get assigned to a record that has those specs. Why duplicate data?

Comment: so @njk , ur saying to create a table containing all the possible combinations of specs that each car can have?

Comment: @Goaler444 That's certainly a viable option; if it's less than having individual specs for all users and does not duplicate data.

Comment: @njk That is quite a good idea and will always make the table static. thanks I will look into it

Comment: @njk What if a user mods his car?

Comment: @JoshC. If there is a table of all combinations, you assign the user a new car. Otherwise, you create a new row for that combination

Comment: @njk while that makes sense and guarantees uniqueness and the minimum set of car records, it creates the need to check for the uniqueness of a record for every create and every edit. Although abandoning a join table may consume more rows, it will probably be easier to develop against and maintain. Just my opinion.

Comment: @JoshC. Uniqueness can be easily enforced. What would be consuming is the realignment of of user to car.